# Analog FM radio like control

Tags: android, input, numbers, controls

I'd like to substitue a normal EditText control (inputType="numberDecimal") to input some decimal numbers with an control we all know from an analog FM radio:

[image]

Basically you have an integer sequence, part of this sequence is visually displayed. You specify a minValue & maxValue, the currentValue is somehow highlighted. Swiping left should increase the displayed numbers, swiping right should decrease them.

Anyone knows if something similar was already implenented in android or has any tips to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most similar project i saw is [Android Wheel](https://github.com/sephiroth74/AndroidWheel)

[image: Screenshot]

It had vibrate effect using permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

To include the wheel widget in the current layout, you should add in the layout xml this lines:

```
<it.sephiroth.android.wheel.view.Wheel
android:id="@+id/wheel"
xmlns:sephiroth="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.sephiroth.android.wheel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
sephiroth:numRotations="6"
sephiroth:ticks="28" />
```

Where numRotations is the max number of rotations the wheel can perform and ticks is the total number of ticks the wheel will display.

Then in your activity you can add a OnScrollListener listener to the wheel widget, in this way:

```
mWheel = (Wheel) findViewById( R.id.wheel );
mWheel.setOnScrollListener( new OnScrollListener() {

@Override
public void onScrollStarted( Wheel view, float value, int roundValue ) {
}

@Override
public void onScrollFinished( Wheel view, float value, int roundValue ) {
}

@Override
public void onScroll( Wheel view, float value, int roundValue ) {
}
} );
```

Another possible useful is [DateSlider](https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider)
[image: SS2]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out both projects! 
I was busy with different stuff today, but will have a look at the code of both tomorrow asap.
Both projects basically use the functionality I'd like to have in my input control, so thats a good starting point to look at.

Will report, if I made any progress on this...

Comment: Had finally some time to invest in this control yesterday. Looking at the DateSlider implementation was exactly what I needed, the code is well documented & easy to understand. Now I have my desired 'number imput control'. Thx again @Yul for pointing out this project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a built in functionality for that.

I have found something similar online here - http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/

To make it something like what you want, you will have to out it in a `framelayout`, and put a textview in the middle which displays the number.

Frame layout - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

I have not looked through that tutorial in much depth, but I would imagine that by changing the image to a horizontal dial, and by changing the `onTouchListener` you will be able to get exactly what you want.

If you have any questions about this ask and I will try to help

Answer (score 0):

Look into Wheel Widget: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

It might do what you want.

Comment: That's assuming there's a horizontal style; I'm not sure there is.

Comment: I don't think the Wheel Widget supports a horizontal style, so I'll have a look at the projects Yul highlighted first.

PS: the control I'd like to have does not need the 'wheel shape', a 'linear shape' like that of a measuring tape is sufficient. The fling gesture to control the input value is the only mandatory feature...